# Google Webhooks getting this error: pushInvalidTtl: Invalid ttl value for channel

Tags: google-api, unix-timestamp, webhooks

When attempting to subscribe to a Google Sheets webhook I am setting the expiration time but receiving the error:

`pushInvalidTtl: Invalid ttl value for channel -1477712661`

This is the call I am making:

```
Google::Apis::DriveV3::Channel.new(
  id: self.id,
  address: "https://#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/api/google/webhook",
  type: "web_hook",
  resource_id: resource_id,
  expiration: (Time.current + 99.years).to_i
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google expects Unix timestamps to be in milliseconds, the above call works when the expiration is set like so:

```
Google::Apis::DriveV3::Channel.new(
  id: self.id,
  address: "https://#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/api/google/webhook",
  type: "web_hook",
  resource_id: resource_id,
  expiration: (Time.current + 1.week).to_i * 1000
}
```

Also, Google doesn't allow you to subscribe to a webhook for longer than a week.

Comment: The maximum expiration seems to vary by API. In my experience with the admin.directory.users API (in 2018) its 6 hours. Anything longer than that will be silently ignored and treated as 6 hours, which also happens to be the default. Very short TTLs will get you a cryptic error like "Invalid ttl value for channel -1523462813". The documentation is missing, wrong, or contradictory. Nice job, Google!

Comment: @jelder The above solution works for me BUT expiration isn't very clear. It seems like the property expires within about 5 minutes. Does anyone know if one can extend the expiration to hours/days or even weeks? If not, how is everyone able to renew  this property? I was thinking of having a cronjob but it seems it would have to renew every few minutes which doesn't make a lot of sense.